# SVG textpath rendering appears reversed in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg

I'm trying to render text along a curved path in an SVG. It renders as expected in Chrome, Safari, and Edge, but it renders differently in Firefox.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hLyq1ug6/

```
<svg width="320" height="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="background: blue"><path d="m57.8,160 a102.2,102.2 0 1 1 204.4,0" fill="red" id="curvedTextPath5cf008a181659"></path><text x="160" y="185.5" style="fill: #ffffff; font-size: 35pt"><textPath xlink:href="#curvedTextPath5cf008a181659" startOffset="0" text-anchor="middle">Hello</textPath></text></svg>
```

Expected:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

Comment: Side note: With SVG 2 (implementation [in progress](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5760616295825408)) you can define whether the text is rendered inward or outward with the new [`side`](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#text-TextPathElementSideAttribute) attribute on the [`textPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've removed the x and the y attributes from the text. If you need to offset the text use `startOffset="50%"`I hope it helps.

```html
<svg width="320" height="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="background: blue">
<path d="m57.8,160 a102.2,102.2 0 1 1 204.4,0" fill="red" id="curvedTextPath5cf008a181659"></path>
<text style="fill: #ffffff; font-size: 35pt">
<textPath xlink:href="#curvedTextPath5cf008a181659" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">Hello</textPath>
</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Per the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#TextpathLayoutRules)

> When the inline-base direction is horizontal, then any ‘x’ attributes on ‘text’ or ‘tspan’ elements represent new absolute offsets along the path, thus providing explicit new values for startpoint-on-the-path.

It seems only Firefox does this correctly.